# Problema com Git/Github - arquivos grandes

Tags: git, github

estou com um probleminha ao criar e subir um repositório git.

Ele tentou subir um arquivo maior que 100.0MB e o GIthub me notificou a restrição. Porém, fui na pasta e apaguei o arquivo. Tentei subir novamente e ele me indica o mesmo erro, mesmo nao havendo o arquivo lá.

Tentei procurar na rede sobre isso e de várias formas e tentativas, não consegui resolver. Alguém pode me ajudar? =)

Comment: você removeu o arquivo, tudo bem, mas deu commit aplicando a remoção? basicamente você precisa comitar a mudança, ou o github vai achar que o arquivo ainda existe.

Comment: Sim, dei o commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amigo realmente tem alguns complicadores, segue um texto de outra resposta para uma pergunta parecida com a sua:

O Git tem uma grande dificuldade com arquivos grandes (>50MB) e uma grande perda de recursos com repositórios grandes (>10GB).

1) Se você está rodando seu próprio git, vai ter que configurar nele um tamanho máximo pros arquivos do repositório. No github, o tamanho máximo de arquivo é 100MB. Mas com 50MB ele já te dá um warn.

2) Git não foi feito pra versionar arquivos binários. É melhor usar um rsync e copiar pra outro lugar.

3) Tem uma solução chamada git-annex para fazer a gestão de arquivos grandes. Dà uma olhada em http://git-annex.branchable.com/

Fonte: [Manusear arquivos grandes com GIT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2308/manusear-arquivos-grandes-com-git)

Comment: Mas esse arquivo não é necessário para o meu repositório. Simplesmente apaguei o mesmo. Porém não consigo dar um push pro rep remoto, pois ele ainda guarda essa memória em algum lugar, me parece.

Comment: você ja deu um git ignore nele ?

Comment: Já tentei também...