# Repositório grande não permite git clone

Tags: git, ubuntu

Posso um servidor com repositórios "private" do git (home made). Estou a ter problemas com um dos repositórios. Acontece que esse repo já atingiu a marca dos 15GB em servidor. Quando tento fazer um git clone do mesmo recebo a mensagem de:

```
error: pack-objects died of signal 9828/1835
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repostiory corruption on the remote side.
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote site.
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Acontece, pelo que percebo, é que esta mensagem é genérica, pois antes tinha os repositórios num raspberry pi. Dava problemas de memória. Ok, troquei para um servidor ATOM com 1 GB de ram a rodar ubuntu server. Nos primeiros commit correu bem, entretanto o repo começou a aumentar e novamente esta mensagem de erro.

Experimentei fazer o seguinte:

Copiar os ficheiros do repo, num dos pc clientes, e iniciar assim um novo repo.
Acontece que antes de fazer "`git add .`" and "`git commit`" a pasta tinha uns 8GB. Após estes dois comandos a pasta ficou com 15Gb. Ok, percebo que se deve ao facto dos arquivos *hidden* que o próprio git cria no pasta do repo para que seja feita a gestão.

A questão é que mesmo após fazer o "`first commit`" neste novo repo tentei fazer o "`git push origin master`" e parou nos 39%. Ao fim de 2 horas assim cancelei o processo.

Por isso temos dois problemas:

1. O repo que está em servidor já não consigo fazer git clone do
   gajo!
2. Tentado criar um novo repo, com os ficheiros do antigo (sem
   os hidden), perdendo assim todos os commit do primeiro repo, não
   consigo fazer o push para servidor;

Nota: No repo original, do lado do cliente, consigo fazer git push origin master, demoram um bocado mas passam! Acontece que apenas tenho o repo num cliente! Sendo que os restantes não tem acesso ao repo porque não é possível fazer o git clone do mesmo.

Estive a pesquisar, e descobri este tópico ([Manusear arquivos grandes com GIT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2308/manusear-arquivos-grandes-com-git)) que fala desta ferramenta: http://git-annex.branchable.com/

Neste momento não sei como resolver este problema. Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Vale a pena dar uma lida: https://git-lfs.github.com/

Comment: Mas tem solução? Ou terei que construir um novo ambiente? Estou com bastante urgência, uma vez que apenas tenho um cópia válida do sistema!

Comment: Pelo que percebo isso é instalado do lado do cliente, certo? No site diz para fazer "git lsf track "*.psd", para rastrear todos os psd. Mas no meu caso pretendo fazer para um repositório completo. Como devo fazer?

Comment: Por que esse repo é tão grande? São arquivos binários? Mídia? Qual o tipo?

Comment: @egomesbrandao São pdf's, mp4, e words!

Comment: Você pode falar um pouco mais da necessidade de ter esses arquivos no repositório? São realmente importante ali?

Comment: @egomesbrandao São! É um repositório que tem que ser partilhado por 4 pessoas. Todos temos que trabalhar em vários excels ou words e consequentemente fazer pdfs dos mesmos! Ao fim de dois meses de trabalho o repo está com um tamanho de +/- 10Gb!

Comment: @EdgarOliveira Gostaria muito de entender essa necessidade... De você ter no meio do processo de desenvolvimento 10Gb de Word, Excel, PDF...

Comment: @egomesbrandao a questão aqui principal é como vou fazer o git gerir isto tudo!? Pelo que já li terei que utilizar o LFS. Sabes me ajudar nisso?

Comment: @EdgarOliveira, a questão não é só essa, estou querendo entender o seu processo e necessidade para te recomendar a melhor solução.
Já vi pessoas guardando milhares de arquivos PDF em repositório sem necessidade alguma, só foi preciso mudar o processo, já que os PDF poderiam ser gerados novamente com dados no banco e não tinham motivos de existir fisicamente.
Neste momento veja se isso te ajuda para começar https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gaTargV5BY